# websockets in micropython? (esp8266)

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, esp8266, micropython

I'm working on a project that requires a control interface in the browser, because some controls are proportional and of very high resolution, it would be best to have a constant stream of data without the need for requests. After some research it appears I need to use a websocket (if there is a better way, that would be an equally useful answer) but the micropython websocket module appears completely undocumented and in fact not baked into my build. Does anyone know of a better module that has some really simple examples for an idiot like me?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use EventSource. It allows your server to easily send a stream of data chunks over a single long-lived connection that can be easily handled in JavaScript (using the EventSource class).

Check out [this example](https://github.com/pfalcon/picoweb/blob/master/examples/example_eventsource.py) in picoweb.

PS: EventSource has some "icing on the cake" features including automatic reconnect, and replay. Discovering these is left as an exercise to the reader XD